# Can you to access Popularity Trends via a query?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I'd like to get the data that comes from Popularity Trends via Power Query and bypass manually clicking the "Popularity Trends" button and downloading an Excel file.

Is that possible?

(The lack of Google results seems to indicate no but maybe I'm now using the correct search phrases?)